# how to send post request in python?

Tags: python, exception, post, request, timeout

i want to send post request in a loop in python
this is my code

```
import json
import requests
url = "http://club.raakdarou.com/users/main/GettingGift"
number=2237499999970255
headers={'Host': 'sample.com',
'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:53.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/53.0',
'Accept': '*/*',
'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
'Referer': 'http://sample.com/users/main',
'Content-Length': '53',
'Cookie': 'ASP.NET_SessionId=4sirmg5n05fkszmvbasr4vnt; __RequestVerificationToken=AsWNgNzLVjU8kCNvWvTjn_tJiBlEKE5NH_xO-o7eGkq3h3av7I1e0_qu6NO80SNKfiV-c5Ajm6nlrDE7pFcKFkdr6ZHVX9zXAWYZt79c_pw1',
'Connection': 'keep-alive'}
     while(number>=2237400000000000):
        number=number-1
        data = {'gift': number , 'X-Requested-With' : 'XMLHttpRequest'}
        r = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(data), headers=headers)
        print(number)
```

when i run this code,everything is ok,but after a while,program stopped(exception happen) and this error shows :  **TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond**..........

(i use wifi to connect to net,and when i connect to my wifi,a hostpot page shows up and i should enter my user and pass,after that,my connection is OK and i can use net.)
what should i do ?

Comment: The `requests` module generally expects the `data` argument to be a `dict` btw. You don't need to format it into JSON.

Comment: @Kendas that depends on the version of the requests library; also, using a dict for "data" will cause it to be form encoded; if the intent is for the dict to be rendered as JSON, one should use the "json" keyword argument, instead.

Comment: @MichaelAaronSafyan Good to know. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think your making too many requests to the site, pause for some time after each request and check.

you can add pause by :-

```
import time
time.sleep(5)        #5 in seconds
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your loop, you're flooding the server. This is an awful lot of requests to send. That's not an algorithm you're writing, it's a DOS attack. Most server have protections against this, and are simply blocking you. If it's not the server, your hotspot is the culprit.

To answer your question : the problem is probably not on your end, you're just triggering securities because you're sending WAY too much requests

Answer (score 0):

Consider how your code appears to the server to which you are POSTing... lots of requests are being sent in a row with no delay from the same sender and with similar parameters; it should be no surprise that a server might perceive this as abusive and throttle or ban the requests. Even without intelligent throttling and rate-limiting on the server, it is quite possible that issuing such a request over and over again might exhaust the server's available resources (e.g. since you attempt to "Keep-Alive" these connections, the server might potentially run out of available sockets).

To fix this, you need to do three things:

1. Add rate-limiting in your code.
2. Add error-handling in your code.
3. Add exponential backoff.

**Rate-limiting**

In short, take an intentional break between requests. For example:

```
 sleep_time_seconds = 3
 while should_send_requests():
   send_request()
   time.sleep(sleep_time_seconds)
```

**Error handling**

Requests can fail. Your code should handle it properly.

```
 def try_send_request():
   try:
     send_request()
     return True
   except requests.RequestException as e:
     # ...
     return False

 # ...
 sleep_time_seconds = 3
 while should_send_requests():
   try_send_request()
   time.sleep(sleep_time_seconds)
```

**Exponential back-off**

When errors occur, you should increase the amount of time between requests:

```
 sleep_time_seconds = 3
 while should_send_requests():
   if try_send_request():
     sleep_time_seconds = 3
   elif sleep_time_seconds < max_sleep_time_seconds:
     sleep_time_seconds *= 2
   time.sleep(sleep_time_seconds)
```